# Is there an option to force partitions on a Snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to look at creating partitions on Snowflake tables and forcing the end user to use them in a query. Intention is to prevent accidental huge queries on large tables

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snowflake does not support "traditional partitions, it has "micro-partitions" which are created automatically. Please read the following document to understand "micro-partitions" of Snowflake:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html#what-are-micro-partitions

The queries will always try to prune partitions based on query filters, but there is no way to force your users to specify a filter condition/partition.

To prevent accidental high credit usage, you may consider "resource monitor" feature. You may create a smaller warehouse, set a resource limit and assign this warehouse to users.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/resource-monitors.html#creating-resource-monitors

Comment: there is a way to force filter conditions. that is either by using views or defining a table udf that returns a table

Answer (score 0):

No you can't create partitions manually in Snowflake, micro-partitions in Snowflake are created automatically based on *when* the data arrives rather than *what* the data contains. You can use cluster keys however to order the data within and across micro-partitions which will help with pruning out partitions when a query is executed.

You could force users to put predicates on their queries by using a BI tool or by parameterising your (secure?)views with a SQL variable and restricting access to the underlying tables. Obviously this would mean that your users would need to set their session variables correctly somehow, probably a bit too restrictive in my opinion but here is an example:

```sql
-- Set variable before creating the view
set predicate_var = 'Mid Atlantic';

-- Create view using parameter in the where condition
create or replace view test_db.public.parameterised_view as 
select 
    * 
from "SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"."CALL_CENTER" 
where CC_NAME = $predicate_var;

-- Select from the view. Only records with 'Mid Atlantic' are returned
select CC_CALL_CENTER_SK, CC_NAME from test_db.public.parameterised_view;
--Results:
--|-------------------+--------------|
--| CC_CALL_CENTER_SK | CC_NAME      |
--|-------------------+--------------|
--|                 2 | Mid Atlantic |
--|                 3 | Mid Atlantic |
--|-------------------+--------------|

-- Change the var to something different to prove it works
set predicate_var = 'NY Metro';

-- Select from the view to show that the predicate has changed
select CC_CALL_CENTER_SK, CC_NAME from test_db.public.parameterised_view;
--Results:
--|-------------------+----------|
--| CC_CALL_CENTER_SK | CC_NAME  |
--|-------------------+----------|
--|                 1 | NY Metro |
--|-------------------+----------|
```

Comment: But maintaining clustering key is another credit consuming part right?

Comment: Yes, but what does that have to do with the question?

Comment: OP wants to save credits for accidental query run by BU.. But the credit will also be consumed in maintenance of clustering key.